# Trying to translate old mysql_query to new PDO method, how to create variable element

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am only having my very first attempt to use the new method, since I was advised to begin using PDO method to instead of the old one for querying the DB.

I cannot figure out how to place the variable into it as I was doing previously with my old one.

here is an old version of my script

```
$file_code = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'fileid' );
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Files` WHERE `fileID`='".$file_code."'") or die ( mysql_error() );
if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
{
die(header("Location: error.php"));
} 
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

and here is my attempt to use the new way to achieve the same result

```
$file_code = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'fileid' );
$db = new PDO($host,$db_name,$db_user,$db_pass);
$res = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE fileID = :".$file_code."');
```

Can you please help me with it since I am not a PRO in php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks guys for pointing me to the right direction, this is exactly why I love Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE fileID = :".$file_code."');
```

What you are doing here is really negating the whole concept of prepared statements.

This is what you should do:

```
$res = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE fileID = ?');
$res->execute(array($file_code));
$data=$res->fetchAll();
```

The beauty of prepared statements is in the fact that you don't need to escape your variables and it's also more efficient if you run it more times.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_code = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'fileid');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;","login","pass");

$res = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE fileID = ?')
                                          ->execute(array($file_code));

$result = $res->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE fileID = :file_code');
$stmt->bindParam(':file_code', $file_code);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE fileID = :file_code');
$stmt->execute(array(':file_code' => $file_code));
```

So you may run [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to pass your values or pass them as an array right to the [PDOStatement::execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php). The first one is much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to ask about your first method, but you have posted it here already. The only difference I have had is $res->bindParam(':file_code', $file_code, PDO::PARAM_INT); this part PDO::PARAM_INT